# Show that $Im T$ and $U/Nuc T$ are isomorphic for a linear transformation $T: U \longrightarrow V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Show that $Im$ $T$ and $U/Nuc$ $T$ are isomorphic for a linear transformation $T: U \longrightarrow V$

Hi guys, I know how to show this for vectorial spaces with finite dimension, but I don't have idea how to show this when vectorial spaces have infinite dimension. Someone can give me a hint, please?

Thanks!

My attempt for vectorial spaces with finite dimension:

If $U$ have finite dimension, so $dim$ $U$ $=$ $dim$ $Nuc$ $T$ $+$ $dim$ $U/Nuc$ $T$ and $dim$ $U$ $=$ $dim$ $Nuc$ $T$ $+$ $dim$ $Im$ $T$, therefore $dim$ $Im$ $T$ $=$ $dim$ $U/Nuc$ $T$

If $U$ have finite dimension, $Im$ $T$ and $U/Nuc$ $T$ have finite dimension, so $Im$ $T$ and $U/Nuc$ $T$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to define $\overline{T}\colon U/\ker T \to V$ by $\overline{T}([x]) = T(x)$. You have to check that

- $\overline{T}$ is well-defined, that is, $[x] = [y] \implies T(x) = T(y)$;
- $\overline{T}$ is injective (take $[x] \in \ker \overline{T}$ and check that $[x] = [0]$, in other words, that $x\in \ker T$, which is almost trivial);
- ${\rm Im}(\overline{T}) = {\rm Im}(T)$

Note that the dimensions of the spaces involved are not relevant for this approach.

Comment: I understood, so to check these things I'll need do this:

[x] = [y] $\longrightarrow$ $\overline{T}$([x]) $=$ $\overline{T}$([y]) $\longrightarrow$ T(x) = T(y);

Suppose that [x], [y] $\in$ Ker $\overline{T}$, so $\overline{T}$([x]) $=$ T(x) $=$ 0 $=$ T(y) $=$ $\overline{T}$([y]) $\longrightarrow$ $\overline{T}$([x]) $=$ $\overline{T}$([y]), if a $v$ $\in$ $\overline{T}$([x]), so $T^{-1}(v)$  $\in$ [x] and $T^{-1}(v)$ $\in$ [y], therefore [x] = [y] because [x] and [y] are class of equivalence. [0] $\in$ Ker $\overline{T}$ because  $\overline{T}$([0]) = T(0) = T(0*0) = 0*T(0) = 0 so [x] = [0]

Comment: I think you misunderstood a few things. In the first item, you have to assume [x] = [y] and prove that T(x) = T(y), without passing through $\overline{T}$, since all of this is to see that $\overline{T}$ is well-defined (and you're only allowed to write $\overline{T}$ *after* you do this). For the second item, you must pick [x] in the kernel and see that [x] = [0], there's no need to take [x] and [y] in the kernel (and I don't see why you did that). In the third item, you can't write things like $T^{-1}(v)$, since $T$ need not be injective.

Comment: and $Im(\overline{T})$ $=$ $Im(T)$ because $\overline{T}$([x]) $=$ $T$(x) but now I have a doubt why $\overline{T})$ go to $V$ and not to $Im(T)$ for $\overline{T})$ be surjective?

Comment: $t^{-1}(v)$ was to proof that [x] = [y] and I proof this because, if [x], [y] $\in$ $ker \overline{T}$, so [x] $=$ [y], in particular, [x] $=$ [0], because [0] $\in$ $ker \overline{T}$

Comment: I think finally check the first item, if [x] $=$ [y], so $x - y$ $\in$ $ker$ $T$, therefore $T(x-y)$ $=$ $0$ $\longrightarrow$ $T(x)$ $=$ $T(y)$

P.S.: sorry if I take time to answer, but my internet is failing

Comment: Don't worry. Your first item is ok now, I've got nothing to correct there :)

Comment: I checked the second item

[x] $\in$ $ker$ $\overline{T}$ $\longrightarrow$ $x$ $\in$ $ker$ $T$ because $\overline{T}$ $([x])$ $=$ $T(x)$.

$x-0$ $=$ $x$ $\in$ $ker$ $T$, so $x ~ 0$ and $[x]$ $=$ $[0]$, therefore $ker$ $T$ $=$ $\{[0]}$ and $T$ is injective.

Now, for the third item, $\overline{T}$ need go to $Im$ $(T)$, not to $V$, correct?

Comment: Yes, $\overline{T}[x] = Tx = 0$ gives $x \in \ker T$ and so $[x]=[0]$, good. Now check that the images of T and $\overline{T}$ are equal

Comment: I think $Im$ $\overline{T}$ $=$ $Im$ $T$ by definition of $\overline{T}$, but I don't see how this ensure that $\overline{T}$ is surjective.

Comment: That's because $\overline{T}$ need not be surjective.

Comment: but the definition of isomorphism is a linear transformation bijective (injective and surjective), so why $\overline{T}$ need not be surjective?

Comment: Because $\overline{T}$, as defined, has domain $U$ and codomain $V$. So for $\overline{T}$ to be surjective, we would've to have ${\rm Im}(\overline{T}) = V$. This is not the case, because one can prove that $\overline{\rm Im}(\overline{T}) = {\rm Im}(T)$. The point is that any injective linear map is an isomorphism *over its image*, and this is what's we're applying here.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry to delay to answer!